# Connect to database via FileDSN in Delphi

Tags: delphi, odbc, delphi-5, dsn, bde

I am trying to connect my TDatabase object to ODBC via FileDSN in Delphi5.
I already created a DSN file and it works very fine when connecting to it via C# or VB6.

For example, the syntax in C# is:

```
private string GetConnectionString(string fileDSNPath, string userName, string password)
    {
        return string.Format("ODBC;DATABASE=library;FILEDSN={0};UID={1};PWD={2};ALLOWUNSCHAR=0;", fileDSNPath, userName, password);
    }
```

Using Delphi 5 IDE, I tried to define TParams but it doesn't work:
TParams:
FILEDSN=[my DSN file path]

[image]

I am getting the error:

> "Unknown Database. Alias: db"

Comment: Looking at the C# it looks like your database is called 'Library'. In the screenshot your DatabaseName field is 'db'. Maybe that is the source of your problem?

Comment: In C#, it works independently of what the value is for Database. I could just write Database=X. In delphi, as per my understanding, the database name help to link other objects such TTable to the TDatabase object

Comment: What database type are you trying to work with?  And have you set up a BDE alias for the database using the BDEAdmin utility?

Comment: I am using AS400. I set BDE alias but maybe in a wrong way. I thought that in the same way that I am doing it in C#, I don't need to setup in BDE for each PC. I just put the DSN file on the network and then all PC can use it

Comment: It's 20 years since I last used the BDE, but my recollection is that it does need to be installed on and configured on each client machine.  Otherwise I'd expect the sort of error you are seeing.  If you've got an ODBC driver for AS400, if I were you I'd use Delphi's ADO components.  Unlike BDE they're not obsolete and ADO is far more robust and reliable than the BDE ever was.

Comment: @MartynA, I presume you understand that it is a very old program that need to be re-write, as you mention about 20 years. Anyway, this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, if you're rewriting it, don't waste any time on the BDE, period.